# 6 seconds delay when using fonts.com service with javascript

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

I want to embed 3 types of Helvetica Neue on my website. The only legal way to do it is to use fonts.com because Linotype work with them. So basically I registered and used their free plan. The only problem here is that I can use only their javascript option which is the catch why this is the free plan. I can use more than 3k fonts, but using the javascript code they provide makes your text load with about 6 seconds delay which is annoying. The only way is to upgrade to standard plan and use their non-javascript option but I have to pay 110$ per year which is a lot giving the fact that I want to use only 3 fonts. 
So my question is can't I just buy those 3 fonts and embed anyhow I want? The buying option in fonts.com is not for web use. Or if I buy 3 types of Helvetica from them, can I embed them in my site using font-face?

Can anyone suggest a solution to use 3 types of Helvetica Neue on my website? I can buy them but I have to be sure that I can use them on my website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The delay introduced by our JavaScript is generally in large part of the FOUT-control methods that ensure that no text using the font is displayed until the fonts in your project are ready.

One thing you can do to minimize this is to make sure your project only includes the fonts you're using. For example, if you're only using those exact three fonts, make sure that they are the only three fonts in your project.

If you would send a support ticket using the ["Need Support?" form](http://www.fonts.com/secure/support) and reference this post, I'd be glad to work with you further. In your ticket, it would be helpful to include either a link to a page where you're using the fonts or the email address on your account and the project you're working with.

Finally, we are also currently evaluating the addition of some advanced options that would allow some control over how the JavaScript implementation behaves.